# How can I use $where in spring data MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongodb-query, where-clause, spring-data-mongodb

I am not able to use `$where` in `SpringDataMongoDb`.

Is there any way to achieve this in `SpringBoot`?

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').find({ $where : function(){
    for (var key in this.action_status){
        return this.action_status[key] == false;
    }
}})
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

1: You can create a repository that extends MongoRepository and have a JSON Query method as follows:

```
@Query("{'action_status':{$eq:?0}}")
public List<YourObj> findByActionStatus(boolean status);
```

2: You can use Query By Object Attribute in MongoRepository. Supposedly you have a field called "isActionStatus" in your object, just declare this method in your repository:

```
public List<YourObj> findByIsActionStatus(boolean actionStatus);
```

Spring Data will break the method name like "select * from ... where isActionStatus = actionStatus

If you need a more complex query you can find the supported keywords here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html

Answer (score -1):

It can be implemented in two ways one is using MongoTemplate and criteria query in spring boot application

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("action_status").eq(false));
List<User> users = mongoTemplate.find(query,MyCollectionClassName.class);
```

Another way is using mongo repository

```
@Query("SELECT mc FROM my_collection mc WHERE mc.status = false")
MyCollectionClassName findMyCollectionClassNameByStatus(Integer status);
```

References :

```
https://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query
```

Comment: This question is about Spring Data Mongo, not Spring Data JPA

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me:

```java
mongoTemplate.find(
   query(
      where("$where").is("this.xyz + this.abc = 123")
   )
);
```

Whereby, the `is` part can be a String which inludes a JavaScript expression. And you can use `this` to refer to the current item.